# GDI Print API StartDoc function is giving inconsistent results

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

In my application a user can have multiple documents open and print all documents to PDF's using a "Microsoft print to pdf" option when they are prompted at the print dialog window, after which they choose the destination folder. Now what happens is that if there are 30 documents selected for print, an inconsistent amount are successfully printed to pdf in the desired folder each time it is run. Sometimes all are successful and other times not. I found that files with unicode character names like this "敥敥敥敥敥敥敥敥" where being created in the same directory as the file of code that contains this print to pdf process. I can rename these files with a ".pdf" extension and they are working pdf documents.

Here is the part of code concerned:

```
DOCINFO docInfo;

memset(&docInfo, 0, sizeof(docInfo));
docInfo.cbSize = sizeof(docInfo);
docInfo.lpszDocName = csPlanoName;
docInfo.lpszOutput = csOutputDir + csPlanoName + csExtension;

if(dc.StartDoc(&docInfo) > 0) {

    //printing process continues
}
```

I found that by stepping through the code, the StartDoc function call would change docInfo.lpszOutput to the same unicode characters "敥敥敥敥敥敥敥敥". This would not happen all the time, and does not happen with specific files when testing. One test a document will print to pdf successfully, another test with the same document and it will create the file with the name "敥敥敥敥敥敥敥敥".

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx#_core_using_cstring_as_a_c.2d.style_null.2d.terminated_string

Comment: Thanks, did have a look at this before I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a string conversion macro seems to have solved my problem, successfully tested outcome 10+ times.

```
CString csFullpath = csOutputDir + csPlanoName + csExtension;
docInfo.lpszOutput = CT2W(csFullpath);
```

Comment: Not really, your issue was caused by use of buffer of temporary string that went out of scope and that you store now as a proper variable `csFullpath` so it survives long enough.

Comment: I don't think so, because I tried the above without the use of the macro and still ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What are `csPlanoName` `csOutputDir`? `docInfo.lpszDocName` and `docInfo.lpszOutput` must be pointers to null-terminated strings and since you are using `csOutputDir + csPlanoName + csExtension` that won't work with regular pointers something else might be happening here. Make sure that result of `csOutputDir + csPlanoName + csExtension` is not getting implicitly cast to pointer and then going out of scope.

Comment: `csPlanoName` `csOutputDir` are CString variables

Comment: Thanks @VTT your answer changed my direction of thinking.